# jQuery UI setting absolute dialog position does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to set the absolute position (x and y) of a jQuery UI (1.12.1) dialog. By all accounts I should be able to do that like so (although the jQuery docs inexplicably do not mention this syntax, neither [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/) nor [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)):

```
$('#element').dialog('option', 'position', [x, y]);
```

Examples of people successfully using this syntax are in:

- [jQuery UI dialog positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744554/616460)
- [Can I make jquery dialog position independent of window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485867/can-i-make-jquery-dialog-position-independent-of-window-size)
- Lots of other places.

Yet, when I do attempt this, nothing happens. Consider the following example (might want to run full screen):

```js
$('#test').dialog({
  width: 200,
  height: 200
});

$('#move').click(function () {
  $('#test').dialog('option', 'position', [30, 30]);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="move">Move</button>
<div id="test" title="test">This is a test.</div>
</body>
```

Run it, press the button, the dialog does not move.

Why isn't this working for me and how do I set the x,y position of a dialog?

Note that the dialog must remain both draggable and resizable after the position change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it to work .. by using

```
position: { my: "left top", at: "left+"+x+" top+"+y+"", of: window }
```

and by reading the [`.position()` documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

I reached to this

```js
$('#test').dialog({
  width: 200,
  height: 200
});

$('#move').click(function () {
  var x = 30,
      y = 30;
  $('#test').dialog({
    //position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: window }
    position: { my: "left top", at: "left+" + x + " top+" + y + "", of: window }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="move">Move</button>
<div id="test" title="test">This is a test.</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome. Yes it's working great. Thanks! I'm going to do it this way, but I'm still kinda curious why `[x,y]` wasn't working for me. Who knows...

Comment: @JasonC I don't know where did you read about `[x,y]` while the dialog documentation is [read dialog position](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)