# JavaScript : How to get the window width and height?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, browser, resize

I want to get the window height and width including Address bar , status bar,etc...

How can I get the window full height and width as shown in the picture below ?

[image]

**Note :** I know about the `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` . It does not suits for this scenario. `window.innerHeight` is used to get the `DOM` height only.`outerWidth` also does not gives what I have want.

Hope our stack users will give a good solution with cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Jquery can be a solution. Read this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596594/jquery-window-width-and-window-height-return-different-values-when-vie

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use this if you want without scrollbars etc.. :

```
window.innerHeight; // for height

window.innerWidth; // for width
```

else in your case, if you want it full, use the below.

```
window.outerHeight; // for height

window.outerWidth; // for width
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using jQuery [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8D36/)

```
$(window).width();

$(window).height();
```

Source [jQuery Window Width](http://www.surfingsuccess.com/jquery/window-width.html#.U0OZ7fmul3E)