# $(window).width() returns the value of which screen monitor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was referring to this link: [jquery $(window).width() and $(window).height() return different values when viewport has not been resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596594/jquery-window-width-and-window-height-return-different-values-when-vie), to get the size of the screen's width.

**Question:** In my code, $(window).width() returns 1024. Is 1024 referring to the screen width of the server machine or the client machine?

Comment: Client machine of course!

Comment: Can you attach any proof or documentation.

Comment: @EthylCasin consider it attached just to the left of your question....

Comment: JavaScript is (typically) client-side. So the result refers to the client. Since it is executed locally without creating a request to the server, it must be the local width. But you might have found this information very easily with a quick google search.

Comment: @EthylCasin That is the height of your browser window so, client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is client side langauge and jquery is a javascript library.

Client side language has no power to access server side funcationality.

So obviously that code will return the client side window size.

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting)

> Client-side scripting generally refers to the class of computer
>   programs on the web that are executed client-side, by the user's web
>   browser, instead of server-side (on the web server). This type of
>   computer programming is an important part of the Dynamic HTML (DHTML)
>   concept, enabling web pages to be scripted; that is, to have different
>   and changing content depending on user input, environmental conditions
>   (such as the time of day), or other variables.

Comment: This is part of the learning process! Learn from your mistakes!